# Two equal sized buttons at bottom of scrollview

Tags: android, xml

I can't for the life of me wrap my brain around this layout. I've managed to get the buttons to the bottom but since they are in a relativelayout I can't get them to both be 50%. Here is what I've got so far, with some code removed for simplification:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dip">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15px">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15px"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>


        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/barcode"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/release"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/other_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/box_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"           
        android:id="@+id/add_bt" 
        android:text="Add to Collection" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/back_bt" 
        android:text="Go Back" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can try using LinearLayout with weights and layout_gravity to bring linear layout down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do they have to be in a `RelativeLayout`?  I think it should work in a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/settingsScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    ...
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_bt"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add to Collection""
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_bt"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Go Back"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've specified a `layout_height` in dp, but you could try `wrap_content` or a different value.

Comment: That worked! I was sure I tried that. Thanks for the help. Note: I did have to add android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Answer (score 2):

Try this. The "trick" is to use some additional LinearLayouts to contain things and then to set the Weight attribute of your 2 buttons to the same value, giving them equal weight.

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15px">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15px"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>


        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/barcode"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/release"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/other_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/box_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"           
            android:id="@+id/add_bt" 
            android:text="Add to Collection" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/back_bt" 
            android:text="Go Back" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout >
</RelativeLayout>
```